# unable to compile program using boost libraries on linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have following program which recursively traverses all the files inside a directory->

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include "string"
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  filesystem::path current_dir("."); //
  boost::regex pattern("a.*"); // list all files starting with a
  for (filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(current_dir), end;
       iter != end;
       ++iter)
  {
    std::string name = iter->path().filename().string();
    if (regex_match(name, pattern))
      std::cout << iter->path() << "\n";
  }
}
```

I compile this program using command:

```
g++ directory_iterate.cpp   -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lboost_system
```

and I get following errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::overflow_error::~overflow_error()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libboost_filesystem.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
```

Comment: have you built boost yourself? or is it part of distribution? Those error suggest real mess with linked libraries

Comment: then it was probably build with wrong static/shared options (link static runtime dynamic etc.). Try rebuilding boost with different linking settings

Comment: actually someone else had built boost on this system. i have no idea how to build it again now @Hcorg

Comment: That is exactly the problem here. You need to rebuild it, or ask your friend to build it all statically.